# How to provide model class for service Angular

Tags: angular

I have a service:

```
export class AddressingObjectListService {
       loadAddressingObjectList(unom: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get(`${environment.addressingObjectUrl}${unom}`, { headers: this.headers });
    }
}
```

And model:

```
export class AddressingObjectListModel {
    public addressingObjectList: any[] = [];
    public objectTotalInfo: any;

    setObjectTotalInfo<T>(data: T) {
         return objectTotalInfo = data;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
this.laodAddressingObject(Number(unom)).subscribe((response: any) => {
   
 });
```

Should I Inject `AddressingObjectListModel` into `AddressingObjectListService` or register `AddressingObjectListModel` as global then fill it like this:

```
this.laodAddressingObject(Number(unom)).subscribe((response: any) => {
     this.AddressingObjectListModel.setObjectTotalInfo(response); 
 });
```

Is it okay to register model class in providers Angular?

Comment: You can create iterface for your model type , no need to register any dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to register a model class in providers. In fact, there is no need to create a class for model objects.

Instead, you should create interfaces.

Something like this:

```
export interface AddressingObjectListModel {
    public addressingObjectList: any[],
    public objectTotalInfo: any;
}
```

Then in your service method,

```
export class AddressingObjectListService {
       
    public loadAddressingObjectList(unom: number): Observable<AddressingObjectListModel> {
       return this.httpClient.get<AddressingObjectListModel>(`${environment.addressingObjectUrl}${unom}`, { headers: this.headers });
    }
}
```

In this way, your response is automatically typecasted into model interface.

Comment: I need to store model somewhere to reuse it in some applications parts. In your case you create model some times

Comment: Simply create a addressing-object-list.model.ts file in shared/interfaces folder and create the interface there. You can then import it wherever you want in the application.

Comment: I talk about model data not interface

Comment: Then you can use ngrx-store for that. Guide link:  https://ngrx.io/guide/store

Comment: just make SharedService added in app.module.ts and update data where